# Adding new DE to a new journey version

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a journey running with a particular DE.

I want to make changes to the DE and launch a new version, so it limits the records to certain criteria, so only these users to enter the new version of the journey.

Would it work if I make a new version and assign a new DE with the field change and leave the previous version "Finishing"?

What would happen to the other records that are in the finishing journey if I change the DE?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the new Journey live, contacts would continue in the current version who have already entered using the current criteria.

Depending on your re-entry settings they could be re-evaluated with the new version's entry settings.

Here is more info:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_create_journey_version.htm&type=5